# Getting Array of duplicate object instead of single object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a rather simple crud app, however, i seem to be stuck on the edit (Edit Controller) portion code. i have a list of student, i select one for update . but i get the error "Expected response to contain an object but got an array".

When i query the webservice directly, i get 
[image]

But when i inspect elements and go to the network tab,  i see this

[image]

here is my code.

```
 var StudentManagement = angular.module('StudentManagement',      ['ngRoute','ngResource','ui.bootstrap']);

 StudentManagement.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "list.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .when("/add", {
        templateUrl: "add.html",
        controller: "AddController"
    })
    .when("/edit/:editId", {
        templateUrl: "edit.html",
        controller: "EditController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });


   });

  StudentManagement.factory('Student', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/Student/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method:   'PUT' } });
 });

 StudentManagement.controller("HomeController",
 function ($scope, $location, Student) {

    $scope.search = function () {
        $scope.students = Student.query();
    };// end search

    $scope.reset = function ()
    {
        $scope.search();
    }// end reset function

    $scope.search();


   });

  StudentManagement.controller("EditController",
  function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Student) {
    // get the student given the specific id
    var id = $routeParams.editId;
    $scope.student=Student.get({id: id});

    $scope.updateForm = function () {
        Student.update({id:id}, $scope.student, function () {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    }// end edit function

    $scope.cancelForm = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    }// end cancel function


});
```

Comment: If you are returning an Array in your API then you should use isArray: true in the service method.

Comment: it should not be returning an Array, thats why i said when call the Api directly from the browser,  it returns [{"id":5,"firstname":"somaya","lastname":"bliss","age":20,"studentId":"1A40000000"}]. Is there any reason as to why an array is being created on the front end?

Comment: its an array...the square bracket denotes an array..you are clearly returning an array from server.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning array of object from server.

So,you should add `isArray : true` in resource defination.

```
  $resource('/api/Student/:id', { id: '@id' }, 
                  { update: { method:   'PUT',isArray : true} 
            });
```

Or

you can return object of object from server

if you want to make current code workable

Comment: Angular doesn't seem to like your addition. the compilation fails.

Comment: oppps,corrected the problem,it should be in action object

Comment: i think i have figured out my problem. will get back to you if it works